# Set the on click method conditionaly in a component

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with an onClick method, where I would like to set the method conditionaly based on the property I get in the component. This is how to code looks like:

```
      <Image
        className={styles.editIcon}
        src={openForm ? editPeriodDisabled : editPeriod}
        onClick={() => toggleFormCallback(id)}
        alt="Rediger periode"
      />
```

I have a boolean property openForm, by which I would like to set the method in the onClick property of the Image component. So, something like this for example:

```
openForm ? null : toggleFormCallback(id)
```

But, not sure how to do that with an arrow function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bind()`:

```
onClick={openForm : null ? toggleFormCallback.bind(this, id)}
```

`bind()` returns a new function which is the same as the original but bound to the given context. You can also bind some or all of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution.

```
  <Image
    className={styles.editIcon}
    src={openForm ? editPeriodDisabled : editPeriod}
    onClick={() => { if (openForm) { toggleFormCallback(id) } }}
    alt="Rediger periode"
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```js
<Image
  className={styles.editIcon}
  src={openForm ? editPeriodDisabled : editPeriod}
  onClick={() => !openForm && toggleFormCallback(id)}
  alt="Rediger periode"
/>
```